# Suggest a sms-gateway

Tags: linux, debian, sms-gateway

I'm looking for good SMS gateway to deploy on Debian machine. Can anyone please suggest good one. Which has UI. Because we are configuring to a client.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it without using sms-gateway.. Thanks All..

I used gnokii to send sms.

Answer (score 2):

i was happily using SIEMENS MC35i industrial gsm terminal. cost of the device was ~120 euro, it has place for one sim card, has external power supply and internal battery.

it was used to send sms notifications from infrastructure monitoring server. i used [scmxx](http://www.hendrik-sattler.de/scmxx/) [[available as debian package](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=scmxx)] to communicate directly with the gateway.